# Questions plagiarised from Quora

Tags: discussion, questions

I noticed that just about every one of user [Jash Jacob](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4840/jash-jacob?tab=questions&sort=votes)'s questions have been lifted from Quora. Can something be done about this?

(I can vaguely recall a ban being handed out. But I'm unsure if it was for this user or someone else.)

---

Here's a list (of ten to start things off) of plagiarised questions:

1. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11536/how-could-princess-leia-remember-her-real-mother-a-little-bit-when-padme-am), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Star-Wars-movie-book-and-general-franchise/How-could-Princess-Leia-remember-her-real-mother-a-little-bit-when-Padm%C3%A9-Amidala-died-in-childbirth)</strike>
2. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11617/does-princess-leia-ever-learn-that-darth-vader-is-her-father), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Star-Wars-Movies/Does-Princess-Leia-ever-learn-that-Darth-Vader-is-her-father)</strike>
3. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/how-can-penny-afford-a-one-bedroom-apartment-on-a-waitress-salary), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/The-Big-Bang-Theory-TV-series/On-the-Big-Bang-Theory-how-can-Penny-afford-a-one-bedroom-apartment-on-a-waitress-salary)</strike>
4. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11469/why-would-q-attach-the-computer-of-a-known-cyberterrorist-to-the-mi6-computer-ne), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Skyfall-2012-movie/Why-would-Q-attach-the-computer-of-a-known-cyberterrorist-to-the-MI6-computer-network)</strike>
5. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11524/why-was-shield-noticeably-missing-from-iron-man-3), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Iron-Man-3-2013-movie/Why-was-SHIELD-noticeably-missing-from-Iron-Man-3)</strike>
6. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11732/who-are-the-three-people-who-could-match-jaime-lannister), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Game-of-Thrones-TV-series/Who-are-the-three-people-who-could-match-Jaime-Lannister)</strike>
7. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/why-was-it-such-a-big-deal-to-dr-xavier-that-magneto-not-kill-sebastian-shaw), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/X-Men-First-Class-2011-movie/In-X-Men-First-Class-why-was-it-such-a-big-deal-to-Dr-Xavier-that-Magneto-not-kill-Sebastian-Shaw)</strike>
8. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11534/why-does-deliberately-causing-a-coolant-leak-in-main-engineering-not-result-in-c), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/In-Star-Trek-First-Contact-why-does-deliberately-causing-a-coolant-leak-in-main-engineering-NOT-result-in-catastrophic-destruction-of-the-ship)</strike>
9. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11503/why-did-frodo-need-to-go-it-alone-leaving-aragorn-and-legolas-behind), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/The-Lord-of-the-Rings-books-movies-and-creative-franchise/In-Fellowship-of-the-Ring-why-did-Frodo-need-to-go-it-alone-leaving-Aragorn-and-Legolas-behind)</strike>
10. <strike>[MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11507/where-does-skyfall-take-place-in-the-bond-timeline), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Skyfall-2012-movie/Where-does-Skyfall-take-place-in-the-Bond-timeline)</strike>
11. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/why-dont-general-zods-people-seem-to-age), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Man-of-Steel-2013-movie/Why-dont-General-Zods-people-seem-to-age)
12. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11975/in-the-film-universe-of-alien-1979-and-aliens-1986-are-the-ships-light-spe), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Alien-movie-series-and-creative-franchise/In-the-film-universe-of-Alien-1979-and-Aliens-1986-are-the-ships-hyperspace-or-warp-speed-capable)
13. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/what-happened-to-agent-k-to-make-him-so-grumpy-and-emotionless), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Men-in-Black-III-2012-movie/After-seeing-Men-in-Black-III-I-still-dont-understand-why-K-became-such-a-cranky-stoical-figure-Per-the-question-that-J-asks-repeatedly-in-the-movie-what-happened-to-K-to-make-him-so-grumpy-and-emotionless)
14. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11457/why-is-adam-dangelos-character-not-in-the-movie), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Adam-DAngelo-1/Why-is-Adam-DAngelos-character-not-shown-in-the-movie-The-Social-Network)
15. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11854/why-didnt-yoda-train-princess-leia-as-a-jedi), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Star-Wars-movie-book-and-general-franchise/Why-didnt-Yoda-train-Princess-Leia-as-a-Jedi)
16. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11486/what-is-the-history-of-aragorn), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/The-Lord-of-the-Rings-books-movies-and-creative-franchise/In-the-Lord-of-the-Rings-movies-whats-the-history-of-Aragorn)
17. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/in-the-empire-strikes-back-why-is-yoda-living-on-that-lonely-remote-planet), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/In-The-Empire-Strikes-Back-why-is-Yoda-living-on-that-lonely-remote-planet)
18. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11699/why-didnt-the-federation-use-swords-against-the-borg), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Star-Trek-The-Next-Generation/Why-didnt-the-Federation-use-swords-against-the-Borg)
19. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11700/why-is-the-witch-king-of-the-nazgul-able-to-be-killed-by-a-woman), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Lord-of-the-Rings-Return-of-the-King-2003-movie/Why-is-the-Witch-King-of-the-Nazgul-able-to-be-killed-by-a-woman)
20. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/what-is-the-role-of-winston-wolfe), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Pulp-Fiction-1994-movie/What-is-the-role-of-Winston-Wolf-in-Pulp-Fiction/)
21. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/why-does-general-zod-need-armor-in-the-man-of-steel-film), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Man-of-Steel-2013-movie/Why-does-General-Zod-need-armor-in-the-Man-of-Steel-film)
22. [MTV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11853/in-star-wars-why-didnt-all-the-jedi-use-the-double-lightsaber-like-darth-maul), [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Star-Wars-movie-book-and-general-franchise/In-Star-Wars-why-didnt-all-the-Jedi-use-the-double-lightsaber-like-Darth-Maul)

**Update:** The user in question appears to have *voluntarily* given away most of the rep gained in the above-listed questions, by creating [bounties](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4840/invnible?tab=bounties) to the tune of 1000 points.

**Update 2:** The user has now deleted his account.

Comment: In fact this has been noticed before (from the exact same user), along with a meta discussion about plagiarism and a suspension for him, I think.

Comment: @ChristianRau i just spotted 5 of his questions before and pinged the mod in chat. There is no meta discussion done before. Even the user got suspended for a week.

Comment: @coleopterist its nice to see someone is keeping eyes open O_o. I have previously notify of his 5 question to mods on chat which are copy from Quora and are posted on the same date. And he is been suspended for even a week. If he has done this on other SE's too then Mod's should investigate it further.

Comment: This is a serious issue we have at our hand. This kills the entire purpose of having sites like this and Quora. Knowledge sharing has alas now been reduced to _rep mongering_.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yet your discussion in chat had spawned a meta thread about plagiarism in general if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't really discuss suspensions here but I would just say that if you can point me at posts plagiarized from any site like Quora - please let us know as we will delete them.

Comment: I don't know if questions should be deleted if answers have also been provided. It might be more prudent to educate/chastise the user and wikify the question instead, depriving him of the rep that he's after.

Comment: @coleopterist - fair point.  A number of posts have been removed already, but clearly a few remain.

Comment: I've added a list of the first 10. FYI, I don't know if wikifying deletes rep. I also don't know if a link back to the original Quora question is necessary; it certainly sounds like the right thing to do.

Comment: @coleopterist - I've wikified those, and a few more.  It doesn't seem to remove rep already accrued, but will prevent future rep.

Comment: Damn, and I hoped so much I didn't write an answer on one of those, now I finally got a stupid CW in my answers. ;-)

Comment: @iandotkelly hmm, can something be done about his rep? Such blatant theft shouldn't be rewarded and he shouldn't receive credit for the question either. Can his account be dissociated from the question?

Comment: @coleopterist - I will see.  The behavior was only noticed fairly recently, and there has been no repeat since.  It would require some specific intervention from SE to do this and I don't know whether they would devote the time to do this.

Comment: @coleopterist He has been notified of his erroneous behaviour and I don't think it has repeated since. We should really wait what happens before burning him at the stake. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau Sure. But I don't think he should benefit from this intentional plagiarism. We are not talking about one or two questions here either. "Rep" and "privileges" are so termed for a reason and IMO, his current rep and privileges are not indicative of his actual worth to this community.

Comment: @ChristianRau I see that he's doing the same thing on [SFF](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14700/jash-jacob?tab=questions) as well. The mods there appear to be aware of it. While they've probably conversed with the user via now-deleted comments, they appear to be content to just stick a "from Quora" link below his question and leave it at that. I've got a feeling that this chap does this on every stack.

Comment: @coleopterist Hmm, interesting.

Comment: @coleopterist - we will take a very dim view on any further plagiarism from him.

Comment: It seems the user has renamed himself and spent most of his reputation in incredibly high bounties on arbitrary questions?

Comment: @iandotkelly I've added the remaining Quora questions that have not yet be CW'd. He appears to have asked one question which is not from Quora. Please do the needful.

Comment: @iandotkelly *bump*

Comment: @coleopterist - noted. Will have a look this weekend.

Comment: @iandotkelly The user appears to have deleted his account. The community wiki is unnecessary. Quora still don't get their required credit, though. Accepting answer.

Comment: @coleopterist - the mods discussed and finally decided to kick the user.  I think he had 1 genuine question we couldn't find a copied source for.

Comment: @coleopterist - now restoring questions .....